# Layout styling with responsive design using CSS

Tags: html, css

I was trying to implement a client manager following the Devbridge knockout example here [Link](https://www.devbridge.com/articles/knockout-a-real-world-example/).

I am trying to make the table based on a div responsive but I'm not sure if there is an easy way other than converting the whole thing to table or some other bootstrap based structure.

I have created a fiddle with vanilla html and CSS that is getting finally rendered on the browser. If I resize the window and make it small the grid gets all distorted. Is there any container I can add to to make it a little bit nicer and responsive?

Here is the HTML. I am not a designer by any means so any quick solution will also be helpful.

```css
body {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

a:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type="text"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.adhoc-container {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 140%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url('images/AdHocMgr/modal-back.png');
}

.adhoc-container-header {
  position: absolute;
  background: #303030;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 60px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 6;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.adhoc-container-title {
  color: #0383df;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 720px;
  margin-left: -340px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.adhoc-container-content {
  display: table-cell;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
  width: 720px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: -360px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.adhoc-container-content-padded {
  position: relative;
}

.adhoc-top-block-holder {
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 30px;
  height: 35px;
}

.adhoc-top-block-controls-holder {
  float: left;
  margin-top: -4px;
}

.adhoc-top-block-controls-holder a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #0383df;
  font-size: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.adhoc-top-block-controls-holder a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.adhoc-add-new-folder {
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding-left: 29px;
  background: url('images/AdHocMgr/sprite-media-1.png') no-repeat -3px -56px;
  height: 30px;
}

.adhoc-upload-new-file {
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding-left: 29px;
  background: url('images/AdHocMgr/sprite-media-1.png') no-repeat 0 -96px;
  height: 30px;
}


/* Sort Arrows */

.adhoc-sort-arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  background: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAGCAYAAAGN9z9QAAAAV0lEQVQI12N4+vTpNCD+zwAjQPgPiAaLIIu6whi3YTJALMSAxIHhaSBBfiSB2zADQdgJZgNMkBmI92IxBoZBcmww3SCsAsQfkBSA2OrIJqLjTCDOQRcHAEn2vvYOPcQQAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC') no-repeat left 4px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 700;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: medium;
}

.adhoc-sort-data {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 700;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: medium;
}

.adhoc-sort {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 700;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.adhoc-grid {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 700;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


/*default sorting block*/

.adhoc-list .adhoc-media-sorting-block .adhoc-media-col-1 {
  width: 40px;
}

.adhoc-media-sorting-block {
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-top: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
}

.adhoc-media-sorting-block>div {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

.adhoc-media-sorting-block .adhoc-media-col-2 {
  width: 170px;
  border-left: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
  border-right: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
}

.adhoc-media-sorting-block .adhoc-media-col-3 {
  width: 180px;
  border-right: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
}

.adhoc-media-sorting-block .adhoc-sort-arrow {
  margin: 8px 0 0 20px;
}

.adhoc-media-sorting-block .adhoc-sort-data {
  margin: 8px 0 0 20px;
}

.adhoc-media-col-2:hover {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.adhoc-media-col-3:hover {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*media manger files*/

.adhoc-list .adhoc-grid-input {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 135px;
  top: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 380px;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: -15px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #1894e4;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 rgba(24, 145, 230, 0.35);
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

input.adhoc-grid-input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.adhoc-add-folder:hover .adhoc-system-addfolder {
  background-position: 0 -297px;
}

.adhoc-system-folder {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 56px;
  height: 42px;
  background: url('images/AdHocMgr/sprite-media-1.png') no-repeat 0 -176px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.adhoc-system-file {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 56px;
  height: 43px;
  background: url('images/AdHocMgr/file.png') no-repeat;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.adhoc-media-name {
  line-height: 16px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.adhoc-media-addFolder {
  line-height: 16px;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #0383df;
}


/*folders in list*/

.adhoc-list .adhoc-folder-box {
  position: relative;
  height: 62px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-folder-box:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-folder-box:hover div.adhoc-system-folder {
  background-position: 0 -235px;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-folder-box .adhoc-icn-edit {
  position: absolute;
  left: 16px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-folder-box:hover a.adhoc-icn-edit {
  background-position: center -869px;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-folder-box:hover a.adhoc-icn-edit:active {
  background-position: center -903px;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-folder-box .adhoc-media-inner-controls {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  width: 130px;
  margin-top: -17px;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-folder-box .adhoc-media-items-block {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 480px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-left: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-folder-box .adhoc-media-name {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 390px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-folder-box .adhoc-media-edit-controls {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 22px;
}


/*folders in list active box*/

.adhoc-list .adhoc-folder-box-active {
  background-color: #effcfe;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-folder-box-active:hover {
  background-color: #effcfe;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-folder-box-active div.adhoc-system-folder {
  background-position: 0 -235px;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-folder-box-active div.adhoc-media-inner-controls {
  display: block;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-folder-box-active div.adhoc-media-name {
  display: none;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-folder-box-active input.adhoc-grid-input {
  display: block;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-folder-box-active .adhoc-icn-edit {
  background-position: center -869px;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-folder-box-active a.adhoc-icn-delete {
  display: none;
}


/*add new folder*/

.adhoc-system-addfolder {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 56px;
  height: 42px;
  background: url('images/AdHocMgr/sprite-media-1.png') no-repeat 0 -126px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-add-folder {
  position: relative;
  height: 62px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-add-folder .adhoc-media-items-block {
  border-left: 0;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-add-folder .adhoc-media-items-block {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-add-folder .adhoc-media-name {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 14px;
}


/*files in list*/

.adhoc-list .adhoc-file-box {
  position: relative;
  height: 62px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-file-box:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-file-box .adhoc-icn-edit {
  position: absolute;
  left: 16px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-file-box:hover a.adhoc-icn-edit {
  background-position: center -869px;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-file-box:hover a.adhoc-icn-edit:active {
  background-position: center -903px;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-file-box .adhoc-media-inner-controls {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  width: 130px;
  margin-top: -17px;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-file-box .adhoc-media-items-block {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 480px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-left: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-file-box .adhoc-media-name {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 390px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-file-box .adhoc-media-edit-controls {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 22px;
}


/*files in list active box*/

.adhoc-list .adhoc-file-box-active {
  background-color: #effcfe;
}

.adhoc-folder-box-applied {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-file-box-active:hover {
  background-color: #effcfe;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-file-box-active div.adhoc-media-inner-controls {
  display: block;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-file-box-active div.adhoc-media-name {
  display: none;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-file-box-active input.adhoc-grid-input {
  display: block;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-file-box-active .adhoc-icn-edit {
  background-position: center -869px;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-file-box-active a.adhoc-icn-delete {
  display: none;
}

.adhoc-list .adhoc-file-box-active .adhoc-edit-buttons {
  display: none;
}


/*additional file types*/

.adhoc-uknown-icn {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.adhoc-media-click-active .adhoc-uknown-icn {
  background-position: -84px 0;
}

.adhoc-file-box:hover .adhoc-uknown-icn {
  background-position: -84px 0;
}

.adhoc-file-box-active .adhoc-uknown-icn {
  background-position: -84px 0;
}

.adhoc-pdf-icn {
  background-position: 0 -112px;
}

.adhoc-media-click-active .adhoc-pdf-icn {
  background-position: -84px -112px;
}

.adhoc-file-box:hover .adhoc-pdf-icn {
  background-position: -84px -112px;
}

.adhoc-file-box-active .adhoc-pdf-icn {
  background-position: -84px -112px;
}

.adhoc-word-icn {
  background-position: 0 -167px;
}

.adhoc-media-click-active .adhoc-word-icn {
  background-position: -84px -167px;
}

.adhoc-file-box:hover .adhoc-word-icn {
  background-position: -84px -167px;
}

.adhoc-file-box-active .adhoc-word-icn {
  background-position: -84px -167px;
}

.adhoc-mp3-icn {
  background-position: 0 -279px;
}

.adhoc-media-click-active .adhoc-mp3-icn {
  background-position: -84px -279px;
}

.adhoc-file-box:hover .adhoc-mp3-icn {
  background-position: -84px -279px;
}

.adhoc-file-box-active .adhoc-mp3-icn {
  background-position: -84px -279px;
}

.adhoc-mp4-icn {
  background-position: 0 -334px;
}

.adhoc-media-click-active .adhoc-mp4-icn {
  background-position: -84px -334px;
}

.adhoc-file-box:hover .adhoc-mp4-icn {
  background-position: -84px -334px;
}

.adhoc-file-box-active .adhoc-mp4-icn {
  background-position: -84px -334px;
}

.adhoc-ppt-icn {
  background-position: 0 -389px;
}

.adhoc-media-click-active .adhoc-ppt-icn {
  background-position: -84px -389px;
}

.adhoc-file-box:hover .adhoc-ppt-icn {
  background-position: -84px -389px;
}

.adhoc-file-box-active .adhoc-ppt-icn {
  background-position: -84px -389px;
}

.adhoc-xls-icn {
  background-position: 0 -446px;
}

.adhoc-media-click-active .adhoc-xls-icn {
  background-position: -84px -446px;
}

.adhoc-file-box:hover .adhoc-xls-icn {
  background-position: -84px -446px;
}

.adhoc-file-box-active .adhoc-xls-icn {
  background-position: -84px -446px;
}

.adhoc-rar-icn {
  background-position: 0 -501px;
}

.adhoc-media-click-active .adhoc-rar-icn {
  background-position: -84px -501px;
}

.adhoc-file-box:hover .adhoc-rar-icn {
  background-position: -84px -501px;
}

.adhoc-file-box-active .adhoc-rar-icn {
  background-position: -84px -501px;
}

.adhoc-wav-icn {
  background-position: 0 -556px;
}

.adhoc-media-click-active .adhoc-wav-icn {
  background-position: -84px -556px;
}

.adhoc-file-box:hover .adhoc-wav-icn {
  background-position: -84px -556px;
}

.adhoc-file-box-active .adhoc-wav-icn {
  background-position: -84px -556px;
}
```

```html
<div class="adhoc-list">
  <div class="adhoc-media-sorting-block">

    <div class="adhoc-media-col-2">
      <a class="adhoc-sort-data">File Type</a>
    </div>
    <div class="adhoc-media-col-2">
      <a class="adhoc-sort-arrow" data-bind="click: sortItems.bind($root, 'Title'), css: { 'adhoc-sort-arrow-top': isSortedAscending('Title'), 'adhoc-sort-arrow-bottom': isSortedDescending('Title') }">File Name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="adhoc-media-col-2">
      <a class="adhoc-sort-data">Username</a>
    </div>
    <div class="adhoc-media-col-2">
      <a class="adhoc-sort-data">Creation Date</a>
    </div>
    <div class="adhoc-media-col-2">
      <a class="adhoc-sort-data">Last Modified</a>
    </div>
    <div class="adhoc-media-col-2">
      <a class="adhoc-sort-data">Variant Type</a>
    </div>
    <div class="adhoc-media-col-2">
      <a class="adhoc-sort-data">Is Public</a>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div>
    <div class="adhoc-folder-box">
      <div class="adhoc-media-items-block">
        <div class="adhoc-system-file"></div>
        <div class="adhoc-media-name" style="width: 160px; text-align: center;">demo data</div>
        <div class="adhoc-media-name" style="width: 160px; text-align: center;">demo data</div>
        <div class="adhoc-media-name" style="width: 160px; text-align: center">demo data</div>
        <div class="adhoc-media-name" style="width: 160px; text-align: center">demo data</div>
        <div class="adhoc-media-name" style="width: 160px; text-align: center">demo data</div>
        <div class="adhoc-media-name" style="width: 160px; text-align: center">
          <input type="checkbox" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="adhoc-media-edit-controls">
        <input type="text" class="adhoc-grid-input" />
        <div class="adhoc-media-inner-controls">
          <div class="adhoc-btn-small">Save</div>
          <div class="adhoc-btn-links-small">Cancel</div>
        </div>
        <a class="adhoc-icn-edit">Edit</a>
        <input class="adhoc-edit-buttons" type="button" value="Apply" />
        <input class="adhoc-edit-buttons" type="button" value="Change Output Order" /> &nbsp;
        <a class="adhoc-icn-delete">Delete</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="adhoc-file-box">
      <div class="adhoc-media-items-block">
        <div class="adhoc-system-folder"></div>
        <div class="adhoc-media-name" style="width: 160px; text-align: center;">demo data</div>
        <div class="adhoc-media-name" style="width: 160px; text-align: center;">demo data</div>
        <div class="adhoc-media-name" style="width: 160px; text-align: center">demo data</div>
        <div class="adhoc-media-name" style="width: 160px; text-align: center">demo data</div>
        <div class="adhoc-media-name" style="width: 160px; text-align: center">demo data</div>
        <div class="adhoc-media-name" style="width: 160px; text-align: center">
          <input type="checkbox" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="adhoc-media-edit-controls">
        <input type="text" class="adhoc-grid-input" />
        <div class="adhoc-media-inner-controls">
          <div class="adhoc-btn-small">Save</div>
          <div class="adhoc-btn-links-small">Cancel</div>
        </div>
        <a class="adhoc-icn-edit">Edit</a>
        <input class="adhoc-edit-buttons" type="button" value="Apply" />
        <input class="adhoc-edit-buttons" type="button" value="Change Output Order" /> &nbsp;
        <a class="adhoc-icn-delete">Delete</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/02bd1Lup/8/)

I am not trying to have someone look at the whole thing and work it out for me, I'm just looking for suggestion to make this whole thing responsive easily without too many changes.

Thanks

Comment: Please include some css to see what you have tried [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It's important that we are able to reproduce the problem here on Stack Overflow. The jsfiddle link could go stale, or people might not have access at work, and then the question makes a lot less sense.

Comment: I added it in the post..Thanks

Comment: At full width the grid renders fine but when I zoom the page or resize it then it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answer would be simple enough for you, but in the css you can use `@media` to check your user's device dimensions and use a specific css rule accordingly like so :

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    /* On small screens, leave a space at the top of the page to put the menu in there. */
    body {
        padding-top: 50px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    /* On large screens, convert the nav menu to a vertical sidebar */
    .navbar {
        height: 100%;
        width: calc(25% - 20px);
    }
}
```

This is just an idea of how you can use it. Hoping it helps.